# Are there any benefits to using ioremap for Port Space Addresses?

Tags: linux, io, linux-device-driver

I'm currently modifying a device driver for Digital I/O board. After examining the device drivers, I saw that I/O is accessed through Port Space Addresses (i.e inb, outb). This results in around 1.5us to access a value. I'm trying to send a CLK signal with around 0.5us pulse so using port space slows down the process I guess.

I saw that `void *ioremap(unsigned long phys_addr, unsigned long size);` can be used to map port space to kernel virtual address. A brief explanation by [@omotto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41713401/2289242)

*Are there any benefits of using this method in terms of access speed?*

*I don't think this could be that easy? What's the catch?*

Best Regards.
Thanks.

Comment: How is the device physically attached?  If it's an ISA device, then you are forced to use I/O mapping.  On any modern bus you can likely use ioremap.

Comment: It's a PCIe device. Would there be a performance increase if I use ioremap?

Comment: The device itself will likely limit I/O speed more than whether you use I/O port mapping or memory mapping.

Comment: That's a bummer. If you want to write an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Mapping IO to memory makes it’s easier for drivers to use single API for IO and MMIO, i.e. `ioreadXX()`, `iowriteXX()`. @stark answered WRT performance.

Comment: `ioremap` is for mapping memory space regions. The generic mapping function is `ioport_map` (or wrappers such as `pci_iomap`). Behind the scenes, `ioread8` etc. will call `inb` etc. for port space regions (and `readb` etc. for memory space regions), so you do not gain any performance.

Comment: I thought `inb` utilizes some special instructions to alter the port space. Whereas, `ioread8` just uses RAM. Isn't this better?

Comment: @DenizdaKing For example, consider [this](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.9/source/lib/iomap.c#L73) implementation of `ioread8` from the 5.9 kernel's "lib/iomap.c": `unsigned int ioread8(const void __iomem *addr)` `{` `IO_COND(addr, return inb(port), return readb(addr));` `return 0xff;` `}`.