# PCIe DMA into system memory without a kernel module

Tags: c, linux, dma

I have a PCIe device with DMA functionality residing under Ubuntu Linux 14.04. I can create a DMA transfer coming from the device (confirmed with an analyzer and target application of DMAing into another device's memory). However, I am struggling to understand how to receive the data from the device to Linux system memory.

I boot with maxcpus=1 to make sure I do not run into cache issues (https://bakhi.github.io/devmem/) and mem=2048M (https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/linux-device-drivers/0596005903/ch15.html) kernel parameters to make sure the kernel does not use the memory I would like to use for my DMA buffer. The Ubuntu PC has 16 GB of total RAM and I am trying to target physical address 0x90000000.

I followed this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41713401 to try to map the physical memory. It appears that the mmap is successful (returns an address). When I try to mmap memory below 2048M, it fails as expected, since it is allocated to the kernel. Before attempting a DMA transfer, I tried simply reading and writing the memory in the C program. When I read the memory, I get some values back. When I read the memory again, I get the same values. This makes me think that the reading might actually be working (not a very strong argument...). When I attempt to read the memory, write the memory and then read it again, I see the original values, as if the write never happened. I tried to start a DMA transfer but I do not see the data arriving in the physical memory as expected.

Here is the code of my exercise:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main()
{
        static volatile uint32_t *gpio = NULL;
        int   fd;
        
        if ((fd = open ("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC | O_CLOEXEC) ) < 0) return -1;
        gpio = (uint32_t *)mmap(0, 0x8000000, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0x90000000);
        if ((int32_t)gpio == -1) return -1;
        
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        {
              printf("0x%08x\n", *(gpio+i));
        }
        
        printf("Press any key when ready to continue...\n");
        getchar();
        *(gpio + 0) = 0x11223344;
        *(gpio + 1) = 0x55667788;

        printf("---\n");

        for (i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        {
                printf("0x%08x\n", *(gpio+i));
        }
        
        munmap((void*)gpio, 0x8000000);
        close(fd);
        
        return 0;
}
```

My goal is to write some data through a PCIe DMA transfer from an end-point to the system memory of the host computer without a kernel module and read the data in the host computer once I know the DMA transfer has occurred. Is this even possible?

Comment: It is possible, but it is not easy. :-) https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.11/driver-api/uio-howto.html

Comment: So, have you flushed caches, I.o.w. Is your system cache coherent? Second question, how did you program MMU for that memory?